# IAM User Permission issue with AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am having an issue with a user that has been unable to access the bucket from last week on Using aws console, and the error messages are as follows:

> > "Insufficient permissions to list objects "You don't have permissions to list buckets After you or your AWS administrator have
> > updated your permissions to allow the s3:ListAllMyBuckets action,
> > refresh this page. Learn more about Identity and access management in
> > Amazon S3"

**The user have the permission for:  abc-ftp ,listBuckets, and cloudfront_admin_policy access**

**Attach policy from group : cloudfront_admin_policy and abc-ftp.**
**Attach directly policy : listBuckets**

**Policy status Limited: List, Read
Policy listBuckets:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Cloud front admin policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cloudfront.abc.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cloudfront.abc.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

An Athena query against the user  :

[image]

[image]

If you know anything, I'd be happy to let you know.

Thank you!

Comment: Access how? Using console or AWS CLI, API? Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: Acess issue with both console and API, the user has that permission only.

Comment: What API/CLI command is used to list the bucket?

Comment: That user has been having an issue with console access for the past week, he gets the error message previously discussed.

Comment: So why did your write "and API"?

Comment: Yes, The user had a problem connecting the AWS console to the S3 buckets.

Comment: Your policies are perfectly fine and they work as expected. It means that you must have some other policies, not shown, which Deny the access.

Comment: If this used to work and now doesn't work, perhaps someone updated a relevant IAM policy or introduced an organization-level policy change that denies the s3:ListAllMyBuckets action.

Comment: There shouldn't be any restrictive permission sets. We use this policy for all employees that need any access to S3. We then add additional policies for the specific buckets they require.

Answer (score -1):

This resolution assumes that the GetObject and PutObject calls are already granted to the AWS Identity Access Management (IAM) user or role. This resolution addresses how to resolve the Access Denied error caused by improper ListBucket permissions or using incorrect sync command syntax with Requester Pays.

Once check the below aws documentation.
I hope this helps :)

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-listobjects-sync/

Comment: Listing objects, which is what that link refers to, is not the same as listing buckets.